# How to fix clang handle_out_of_bounds error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, c99

I'm currently compiling my C99 code with clang's compiler flag `-fsanitize=array-bounds` and it produced a "__ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds" error here:

```
void _add_entry(const char* api_name, void* api_ptr) {
    int id = _produce_id_from_string(api_name);

    ASSERT(_api_hash_map.entry_index < MAX_ENTRIES);

    _key_value_pair* map_entry = &_api_hash_map.entries[_api_hash_map.entry_index++]; //out of bounds
    map_entry->unique_id = id;
    map_entry->value = (uintptr)api_ptr;
};
```

So I tried putting the `_api_hash_map.entry_index' inside an if to get rid of the error:

```
void _add_entry(const char* api_name, void* api_ptr) {
    int id = _produce_id_from_string(api_name);

    ASSERT(_api_hash_map.entry_index < MAX_ENTRIES);

    if(_api_hash_map.entry_index < MAX_ENTRIES) {
        _key_value_pair* map_entry = &_api_hash_map.entries[_api_hash_map.entry_index];
        map_entry->unique_id = id;
        map_entry->value = (uintptr)api_ptr;
        _api_hash_map.entry_index++;
    }
};
```

but to no avail. To check, I simplified things further and just wrote:

```
void _add_entry(const char* api_name, void* api_ptr) {
    int arr[10] = { 0 };
    arr[3] = 23;
};
```

but still receive the error. I must be misunderstanding how `-array-bounds` checking works in clang. What am I missing

Edit:

My current build file for clang is:

```
@echo off

REM This represents the full directory path to your batch file
set cwd=%~dp0

call "C:\msvc\setup.bat"

REM -fno-stack-protector tells compiler to not worry about security calls (like __security_cookie) that would typically be inserted with c libs. -mstack-probe-size=99999999999 basically says don't worry about __chkdsk for checking stack overruns
REM Note that the -Wpadded option isn't really working at the moment. I think there is a github issue on this open so we'll have to see if this is fixed in a later version (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58100)
set compiler_flags=-g -fdebug-macro -O0 -fno-stack-protector -Wall -Wpadded -mstack-probe-size=9999999 -fno-builtin -std=c99 -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -fsanitize=array-bounds

REM -STACK:0x100000,0x100000 is setting function stack default to 1MB. Can increase this if we need to. Keep in mind though this also increases default stack size for all threads created
set linker_flags=-subsystem:windows -machine:x64 -incremental:no -opt:ref -debug:full -ignore:4099 -NODEFAULTLIB -STACK:0x100000,0x100000

set include_paths=-I"%cwd%source" -I"C:\msvc\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um"
set library_paths=-LIBPATH:"C:\msvc\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" 
set import_libraries="kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "glew32s.lib" "opengl32.lib" "gdi32.lib"

IF NOT EXIST bin mkdir bin
pushd bin

clang --compile ..\source\editor.c %compiler_flags%
lld-link editor.o -dll %linker_flags% -export:editor_update -noentry

clang --compile ..\source\win64_main.c %compiler_flags% %include_paths% -I"%cwd%dep\glew-2.1.0\include" -DBGZ_WIN64 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-null-dereference
lld-link win64_main.o -OUT:win64_main.exe %linker_flags% %library_paths% %import_libraries% -LIBPATH:"%cwd%dep\glew-2.1.0\lib\win64-release"
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
----- Build Debug x64 -----
Executing build command:
clang_build.bat
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds
>>> referenced by D:\User Program Files_Data\software_projects\bgz_engine\source\api_directory.h:52
>>>               win64_main.o:(_add_entry)
>>> referenced by D:\User Program Files_Data\software_projects\bgz_engine\source\api_directory.h:74
>>>               win64_main.o:(_get_api)
>>> referenced by D:\User Program Files_Data\software_projects\bgz_engine\source\stb_sprintf.h:595
>>>               win64_main.o:(stbsp_vsprintfcb)
>>> referenced 209 more times
===== Success : 1 errors, 0 warnings =====
```

Comment: what version of clang are you using? I tried a few random ones on godbolt and [could not reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/7WaxqP6bG). <O/T>, you don't need a trailing `;` after the `}` when you close out a function.

Comment: clang version 14.0.6. Ya, it seems to work on godbolt. I'll post the error message I'm receiving as well as my clang_build.bat file